# Having Trouble Formatting Website for All Resolutions

Tags: html, css, background-color

Hello fellow techies who will fix your relatives computer for free,

Anyway, I am a fairly new coder, and am only still a beginner in HTML/CSS. As a first project, I am making a website for my Dad as a birthday present, because he hasn't updated his small business' website in about 15 years, and gets most of his work through his rep, but I want to help him out and bring it into the 21st century.

Anyway, I followed a few YT tutorials on how to create a simple website, but ATM my website is about 800px across, and it looks like his current website since no matter what size your screen is, the text only fills up about 1/3-1/2 of the screen.

The main thing I want first of all is for the background colors, especially the header, to bleed off screen, and secondly, for the text/pictures to scale as you change the browser size.

I tried looking for some answers on other threads, but it was hard for me to understand since the other people had their own names for their dividers and variables.

Here is a portion of my HTML and CSS. Of course I cut out most of the code like most of the text, text formatting, etc, as well as names and places.

HTML:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
<h1>Dad's Company</h1>
</div>
<div id="content">
<div id="main">
<h2>Person Name</h2>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id= "footer">
Copyright &copy; 2017 Ye Co.
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
----------
```

This is the CSS

```
body {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

h1 {
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    color: #4F4F4F;
    text-align: center;
}

#header {
    background-color: #992626;
}

#container {
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

 #site { 
    overflow-x: hidden; 
 }

#content {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
}

#main {
    width: 600px;
    float: center;
}

#footer {
    clear: both;
    font-size: 15;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #992626;
    font-family: serif;
```

Thanks!
I hope you guys can find an answer through my messy coding. It will also help if you guys can give me an example of some of you code instead to show me a solution. Thanks!

Comment: try using bootstrap's grid layout.  It makes this kind of thing super easy.

Comment: Thanks, I like to learn by messing with others's people code anyway. But maybe someone will have an answer before I figure it out.

Answer (score -1):

Remove id="main", you get proper alignment of paragraph.

Comment: I don't think you read the question. I am trying to get my background color of the header to spread across the webpage, even in different resolutions. I already know about the "main" text alignment, because I am putting other text there which I excluded for the sake of cleaning up the code for the question.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
<style>
body {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

h1 {
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    color: #4F4F4F;
    text-align: center;
}

#header {
    background-color: #992626;
}

#container {
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

 #site { 
    overflow-x: hidden; 
 }

#content {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
}

#main {
    width: 600px;
    float: center;
}

#footer {
    clear: both;
    font-size: 15;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #992626;
    font-family: serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
<h1>Dad's Company</h1>
</div>
<div id="content">
<div >
<h2>Person Name</h2>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id= "footer">
Copyright &copy; 2017 Ye Co.
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```